# convert postgresql table to xml

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table with following columns

classificazione_dpr_412,superficie_utile_riscaldata,    classe_energetica,    epgl_n_ren,    tipo_intervento_1,    tipo_intervento_2,    tipo_intervento_3,    superficie_disperdente,    rapporto_asol_asup,    tipo_impianto,    anno_installazione_generatore,    combustibile,    potenza_nominale,    efficienza_media_stagionale,    ep_nren_clim_inv,    ep_nren_acs,    ep_nren_illuminazione,    comune,    regione,    ep_nren_standard_rif

and need a postgresql query to transform it into following xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ape2015 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<datiGenerali>
<classificazioneDPR412>"classificazione_dpr_412"</classificazioneDPR412>
<datiIdentificativi>
<superficieUtileRiscaldata> "superficie_utile_riscaldata"</superficieUtileRiscaldata>
</datiIdentificativi>
</datiGenerali>
<prestazioneGlobale>
<prestazioneEnergeticaGlobale>
<classificazione>
<classeEnergetica>"classe_energetica"</classeEnergetica>
<epglnren> "epgl_n_ren"</epglnren>
</classificazione>
</prestazioneEnergeticaGlobale>
</prestazioneGlobale>
<raccomandazioni>
<interventoRaccomandato>
<codice>"tipo_intervento_1"</codice>
<tipoInterventoRaccomandato>"tipo_intervento_1"</tipoInterventoRaccomandato>
</interventoRaccomandato>
<interventoRaccomandato>
<codice>"tipo_intervento_2"</codice>
<tipoInterventoRaccomandato>"tipo_intervento_2"</tipoInterventoRaccomandato>
</interventoRaccomandato>
<interventoRaccomandato>
<codice>"tipo_intervento_3"</codice>
<tipoInterventoRaccomandato>"tipo_intervento_3"</tipoInterventoRaccomandato>
</interventoRaccomandato>
</raccomandazioni>
<datiFabbricato>
<superficieDisperdente> "superficie_disperdente"</superficieDisperdente>
<rapportoAsolAsupUtile> "rapporto_asol_asup"</rapportoAsolAsupUtile>
</datiFabbricato>
<datiImpianti>
<climatizzazioneInvernale>
<impianto>
<tipoImpianto>"tipo_impianto"</tipoImpianto>
<annoInstallazione>"anno_installazione_generatore"</annoInstallazione>
<vettoriEnergeticiUtilizzati>
<vettore>"combustibile"</vettore>
</vettoriEnergeticiUtilizzati>
<potenzaNominale> "potenza_nominale"</potenzaNominale>
</impianto>
<efficienza> "efficienza_media_stagionale"</efficienza>
<prestazione>
<epnren> "ep_nren_clim_inv"</epnren>
</prestazione>
</climatizzazioneInvernale>
<produzioneACS>
<prestazione>
<epnren> "ep_nren_acs"</epnren>
</prestazione>
</produzioneACS>
<illuminazione>
<prestazione>
<epnren> "ep_nren_illuminazione"</epnren>
</prestazione>
</illuminazione>
</datiImpianti>
<datiExtra>
<comune>"comune"</comune>
<regione>"regione"</regione>
<EPglnrenRifStandard> "ep_nren_standard_rif"</EPglnrenRifStandard>
</datiExtra>
</ape2015>
```

I need a proper postgresql query to transform postgresql table into xml file.

Comment: [table_to_xml](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING)

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing query directly in tools or console, you can use tools like DataGrip which will give you an option to export files in various options including XML.

If you are executing a query inside an application, it should be very easy to convert JSON or Object data to XML. You do not need SQL to convert data into XML file.